# It is possible to update 2 column form 1 lookup?

Tags: c#, sql-server, axapta, x++

im looking for a solution of my problem. I got 2 columns and I get for the first data from lookup. But is it possible to update the second column with data too ? 
In first column i get a ID and in want that it automatically updates the second column with the NAME for this ID.  DONE

```
 public void lookup()
    {
        Query query = new Query();
        QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;
        QueryBuildRange queryBuildRange;
        HcmWorkerStaging hcmworkerstaging;


        SysTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(HCMWORKERSTAGING), this);

        sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(HCMWORKERSTAGING, PhoneticMiddleName));
        sysTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(HCMWORKERSTAGING, NameAlias));

        queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tableNum(HCMWORKERSTAGING));

        sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

        sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();



       // super();
    }
```

Comment: Added new question / problem/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it´s possible.

You must override the `modified` method of that field (same field you do the lookup).

***Example according to your code:***

`Modified` method is execute before the `Lookup` Method and has the value that was selected.

```
public void modified()
{

    HcmWorkerStaging hcmworkerstaging;

    super();

    select * from hcmworkerstaging where hcmworkerstaging.PhoneticMiddleName == YourDataSource.YourField1;
    if(hcmworkerstaging)
    {
        YourDataSource.YourField2 = hcmworkerstaging.NameAlias;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great it updates now but still i dont know how to catch the data so I can put it into this field. (sorry im poor at coding it)

Comment: Edit answer according your code, remember mark as correct the answer if helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks ! It works but partialy. The value is ok but when i change again it didnt modified to match the new ID.
Anyway I have one last problem but idk if I should make anoteher thread for it. I need to make a dynamic filter for NAME. For every character i type it filters and gives values that cointain somewhere a letter or word. Managed only to make a simple filter in it that search for first matched word :/

Comment: Radoslaw,  It is not recommended that you make a response with a query, you must modify your original query.

As for the solution is correct, only that it must have been implemented or done incorrectly.

Comment: True, my fault. I must be tired... did twice the same field name. Now it works fine. Now i need only to make this filters.

Comment: Ok, perfect, It is important that you mark my answer as correct to help other users like you.

Comment: SOLVED. Just made something like this: queryBuildRange.value(queryvalue("P?????????"));


One more question here. It is possible to code a queryrange with number of characters ? In my db are some broken records that don't work too good and they have different IDs from the other. the broken have 8 characters (P0000001) and the good ones 10 chars (P000000001) and i need only to use the good ones.